# How can i integrate Azure Mobile App win Azure API app

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-api-apps

We are building a mobile cross platform solution with Xamarin (Xamarin.Forms).
We developed a backend API in Azure with Azure API Apps.
Now we want to integrate and use Mobile Apps (Mobile Services) but using Azure API Apps we created previously.
I see this BUILD presentation https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/3-623
and the idea i think is to use ApiController and call to Azure API Apps there.

Is this correct? Some sample? How can i do? I must have 2 projects API Apps + Mobile Apps? or I must integrate in one (only one API)?

Comment: sorry, but I could not understand what you want. Mobile Apps gives you a few things like authentication, push notification and other features to accelerate your development. I'm thinking that your Api just expose your business rules. If so, then yes, you can combine them and you'll have two projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially have your mobile clients connect to your API app, but you'll have an easier time if you convert your API App to use the Mobile App backend packages. Another option is to have your Mobile App backend connect to the API app, but that's a lot of hops without much benefit.

For details on these packages, see [How to work with the .NET backend server SDK for Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/).

For a step-by-step tutorial, start with [Create a Xamarin.Forms app on Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-xamarin-forms-get-started-preview/).