# Azure API App how to use single hosted api for both Mobile and Web

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, azure-mobile-services, azure-api-apps

This question is related to following questions but not the same question

[How can i integrate Azure Mobile App win Azure API app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233762/how-can-i-integrate-azure-mobile-app-win-azure-api-app)

[How to combine azure AppServices API, Mobile and Web apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37453155/how-to-combine-azure-appservices-api-mobile-and-web-apps)

I have been trying to setup an API to use with my mobile app(Xamarin) and Web app(Angular or ASP.NET MVC). I wanted to use "Azure App Service".
As i understand there are three things in Azure app service

1. Web Apps
2. Mobile Apps
3. API Apps

I wanted to select the "API APPS" as i wanted to use my Existing ASP.Net Web Api and wanted to expose the Api to swagger. Also I wanted to share this api with Mobile app as well as Web App.

Based on the documentation "API APPS" can be consumed by Mobile and Web clients.Web client is OK but i need to use Azure Mobile features(such as Single Authentications,Notifications,Offline Sync with Sql lite and etc ) to make things easy in Mobile app.

As per answers for above questions and the documentation, i can install mobile [app back-end packages](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server) to ASP.Web API and host it as "Mobile APPS". So i can use all the features related to mobile.

1. My problem if i install the mobile back-end, can i use the same API
   for Web Front end? Because I am hosting it as "Mobile APPS" service
   not the "API APPS" service.
2. How can I share a single API host with mobile client (With Mobile back end feature) and Web client?
3. Is it possible to install the Mobile back-end packages and host the
   API as "API APPS" , then use Mobile SDK in Xamarin app and the HTTP client or other client in Web APP to consume the same API?

Comment: 1.Yes 2. Yes. 3.Yes & No depending on the packages you install. I suggest you go with a full blown asp core web api. Notifications can be handled via the pushapp library https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp

Comment: @MichaelIchangai Thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use the Azure Mobile client SDK, especially features like offline sync, then you need to use the [Azure Mobile server SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/). It's a set of NuGet packages that simply extend ASP.NET Web API.

If you want to roll your own mobile client, or just use the authentication feature, then you don't need to use the Azure Mobile server SDK and you can use just Web API.

If you do want to use the server SDK, we have samples that show how to consume this TableController API from a web client:

- https://github.com/azure-appservice-samples/contosomoments
- [Azure App Service field engineer sample with web admin portal and offline-sync-enabled Xamarin.Forms client](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/app-service-mobile-dotnet-fieldengineer/)

Comment: Thank you ! last answer is what i am looking for.So we can consume Mobile Apps API in web client as we normally consume the Web API .There is no any restriction in terms of Mobile Apps API

Comment: That's correct, there are no restrictions here. Please accept my post if it answered your question. :)

Comment: Thanks sure i will do :)